# Using state from other class

Tags: reactjs

I'm creating my university project. Some kind of tracker using ReactJS as frontend and I wan't to have global variable, used in any class I want to. This variable gonna be responsible for things shown at the screen. Let's say there are 10 users. I'm on first and after I use button, variable increases, I'm sending web request with other ID and next user loads. Is there any way to have such variable? Can I use "globalID" like that? I want to go step by step. At this moment I just want to have such global variable. I'm gonna think about rendering and web request later.

Untill now I've tried to extend from App, so I can maybe use this state value. Still, nothing worked. Idk, maybe there is method for that.

````
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      globalID: "",
      ...
    };
  }

  ...
}

class Proteges extends App {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      ...
      userResponse: []
    };
    ...
  }

  ...

  getUserByID() {
    fetch(`http://localhost:9000/proteges/${HERE I WANT TO USE globalID}`)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(res => this.setState({ userResponse: res }))
      .catch(err => err);
  }

  ...

  componentDidMount() {
    ...
    this.getUserByID();
  }

  increaseID() {
        // FUNCTION TO INCREASE ID
        console.log(...)
  }

  decreaseID() {
        // FUNCTION TO DECREASE ID
        console.log(...)
  }
 ...

  render() {
    return (
      <div id="proteges">
        <div>
          <span>
          <!-- THIS BUTTON SHOULD DECREASE globalID by 1 and reload #proteges div -->
            <Button 
            variant="success" 
            size="md" 
            onClick={this.increaseID} 
            active>
              <strong> &laquo; </strong>                        
            </Button>
          </span>
          ...
          <span>
          <!-- THIS BUTTON SHOULD INCREASE globalID by 1 and reload #proteges div -->
            <Button 
            variant="success" 
            size="md" 
            onClick={this.decreaseID} 
            active>
              <strong> &raquo; </strong>                        
            </Button>
          </span>
        </div>
        ...
    );
  }
}

...

export default App;
```
````

Comment: Technically, if every one of your components are children of one parent component, you could pass the state as props to each of them. However, if you want to manipulate this state in any way, and considering you're also working with a back-end, I'd suggest adding [Redux](https://react-redux.js.org/) to your project. It's an investment of time that's really worth it, and it doesn't take a lot of knowledge to already be able to add a lot of functionality to your project.

Comment: Yea, I thought about Redux, but just wasn't sure if that wont be too much. Most of my university peers went for easy way, with php and maybe two houndred code lines, where I have like 1.5 thousand now, 350 reactjs and 1k+ nodejs. Still, gonna check this redux. Maybe it's time to do so.

Comment: Or use [mobx](https://mobx.js.org) as alternative for Redux.

Comment: I am not sure I understand: is this global variable shared between frontends, or is it per frontend?

Comment: you can use context api to store this global value.

Answer (score 0):

You could try experimenting with `window.globalID = '<id_here>'` and/or `localStorage.setItem('GlobalID', '<id_here>')` and `localStorage.getItem('GlobalID')`.